# How to subset columns under a merged cell in R

Tags: r, csv, header

I'd like to select only Game2 column from all the cities for all the Names and add a new column to indicate which cities these are from like below:

| Name | Number | Game2 | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | 2453 | 11 | Toronto |
| Anna | 2453 | 10 | Montreal |
| Anna | 2453 | 10 | Vancouver |
| Louisa | 6532 | 23 | Toronto |
| Louisa | 6532 | 8 | Montreal |
| Louisa | 6532 | 9 | Vancouver |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

This is what the df looks like in csv

[image: img]

And below is how R reads it with the

```
structure(list(NA. = c("Name", "Anna", "Louisa", "Cheryl", "Amanda", 
"Kathleen", "Aisha", "Solange", "Mary", "Jameela"), NA..1 = c("Number", 
"2453", "6532", "3467", "9836", "1784", "7776", "9867", "3726", 
"2289"), Toronto = c("Game1", "12", "6", "7", "10", "12", "9", 
"11", "9", "10"), NA..2 = c("Game2", "11", "23", "10", "9", "7", 
"13", "8", "10", "9"), NA..3 = c("Game3", "5", "11", "10", "8", 
"9", "10", "10", "8", "9"), Montreal = c("Game1", "7", "13", 
"14", "7", "9", "13", "9", "7", "11"), NA..4 = c("Game2", "10", 
"8", "10", "9", "10", "11", "7", "8", "10"), NA..5 = c("Game3", 
"6", "12", "11", "9", "9", "10", "12", "8", "12"), Vancouver = c("Game1", 
"11", "10", "9", "7", "8", "8", "9", "6", "10"), NA..6 = c("Game2", 
"10", "9", "9", "9", "8", "10", "10", "9", "10"), NA..7 = c("Game3", 
"9", "10", "11", "11", "10", "12", "11", "8", "12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Please see my previous edit suggestion to your question for how to fix the formatting problems you just reinserted into it. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67692201/revisions

Answer (score 1):

### base R

First, save the cities and remove them from the data.

```r
cities <- colnames(dat)
colnames(dat) <- unlist(dat[1,])
dat <- dat[-1,]
cities <- gsub("NA\\.*[0-9]?", "", cities)
cities
#  [1] ""          ""          "Toronto"   ""          ""          "Montreal"  ""          ""          "Vancouver" ""         
# [11] ""         
cities <- ave(cities, cumsum(nzchar(cities)), FUN = function(z) z[1])
cities
#  [1] ""          ""          "Toronto"   "Toronto"   "Toronto"   "Montreal"  "Montreal"  "Montreal"  "Vancouver" "Vancouver"
# [11] "Vancouver"
colnames(dat) <- paste0(cities, ifelse(nzchar(cities), "_", ""), colnames(dat))
```

At this point, you should know that all of your number-like columns are still strings. If you want to fix this, you can do `dat[] <- lapply(dat, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)`.

Now, we need to reshape/pivot to long to be able to safely break-apart city from the game.

```r
datlong <- within(reshape2::melt(dat, c("Name", "Number")), {
  City = gsub("_.*", "", variable)
  game = gsub(".*_", "", variable)
  variable = NULL
})
head(datlong)
#       Name Number value  game    City
# 1     Anna   2453    12 Game1 Toronto
# 2   Louisa   6532     6 Game1 Toronto
# 3   Cheryl   3467     7 Game1 Toronto
# 4   Amanda   9836    10 Game1 Toronto
# 5 Kathleen   1784    12 Game1 Toronto
# 6    Aisha   7776     9 Game1 Toronto
```

and then reshape again ti break each game into its own column (I'm inferring that's you're preference).

```r
reshape2::dcast(datlong, Name + Number + City ~ game)
#        Name Number      City Game1 Game2 Game3
# 1     Aisha   7776  Montreal    13    11    10
# 2     Aisha   7776   Toronto     9    13    10
# 3     Aisha   7776 Vancouver     8    10    12
# 4    Amanda   9836  Montreal     7     9     9
# 5    Amanda   9836   Toronto    10     9     8
# 6    Amanda   9836 Vancouver     7     9    11
# 7      Anna   2453  Montreal     7    10     6
# 8      Anna   2453   Toronto    12    11     5
# 9      Anna   2453 Vancouver    11    10     9
# 10   Cheryl   3467  Montreal    14    10    11
# 11   Cheryl   3467   Toronto     7    10    10
# 12   Cheryl   3467 Vancouver     9     9    11
# 13  Jameela   2289  Montreal    11    10    12
# 14  Jameela   2289   Toronto    10     9     9
# 15  Jameela   2289 Vancouver    10    10    12
# 16 Kathleen   1784  Montreal     9    10     9
# 17 Kathleen   1784   Toronto    12     7     9
# 18 Kathleen   1784 Vancouver     8     8    10
# 19   Louisa   6532  Montreal    13     8    12
# 20   Louisa   6532   Toronto     6    23    11
# 21   Louisa   6532 Vancouver    10     9    10
# 22     Mary   3726  Montreal     7     8     8
# 23     Mary   3726   Toronto     9    10     8
# 24     Mary   3726 Vancouver     6     9     8
# 25  Solange   9867  Montreal     9     7    12
# 26  Solange   9867   Toronto    11     8    10
# 27  Solange   9867 Vancouver     9    10    11
```

### dplyr

Starting *after* `colnames(dat) <- paste0(.)` from above (since that is not as easily dplyr-ized);

```r
head(dat)
#       Name Number Toronto_Game1 Toronto_Game2 Toronto_Game3 Montreal_Game1 Montreal_Game2 Montreal_Game3 Vancouver_Game1 Vancouver_Game2 Vancouver_Game3
# 2     Anna   2453            12            11             5              7             10              6              11              10               9
# 3   Louisa   6532             6            23            11             13              8             12              10               9              10
# 4   Cheryl   3467             7            10            10             14             10             11               9               9              11
# 5   Amanda   9836            10             9             8              7              9              9               7               9              11
# 6 Kathleen   1784            12             7             9              9             10              9               8               8              10
# 7    Aisha   7776             9            13            10             13             11             10               8              10              12
```

Then continuing:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*, separate
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Name, Number)) %>%
  separate(name, c("City", "game"), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Name, Number, City), names_from = game, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 27 x 6
#    Name   Number City      Game1 Game2 Game3
#    <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
#  1 Anna   2453   Toronto   12    11    5    
#  2 Anna   2453   Montreal  7     10    6    
#  3 Anna   2453   Vancouver 11    10    9    
#  4 Louisa 6532   Toronto   6     23    11   
#  5 Louisa 6532   Montreal  13    8     12   
#  6 Louisa 6532   Vancouver 10    9     10   
#  7 Cheryl 3467   Toronto   7     10    10   
#  8 Cheryl 3467   Montreal  14    10    11   
#  9 Cheryl 3467   Vancouver 9     9     11   
# 10 Amanda 9836   Toronto   10    9     8    
# # ... with 17 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

you can "subset" your data frame and assign the names, etc. "by hand".
The subsetting notation ``df[rows, cols]` allows you to specify which part of the rows/cols you want to use.
Obviously, you have nested column names - which is not ideal.

```
library(dplyr)   # using the tidyverse for data crunching

df_Toronto <- df[2:nrow(df),1:5]    # take 2nd row till end and cols 1 through 5
my_names   <- c("Name", "Number", "Game1","Game2","Game3")
names(df_Toronto) <- my_names
df_Toronto <- df_Toronto %>% 
   select(Name, Number, Game2) %>%     # pick your desired columns
   mutate(City = "Toronto")            # add a new city column

## do the same for Montreal and Vancouver

## combine all dataframes
df <- bind_rows(df_Toronto, df_Montreal, df_Vancouver)
```

If your data set is significantly larger, you can turn this into a function.